# Angular / Ionic Input with null value changed to 0

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, null, ngmodel

one Problem. I manage Soccer Scores with an Ionic (Angular) project.

My game model:

```
opponent: "TSV Marktbergel"
scoreOpponent: null
scoreSvl: null
```

Function save():

```
saveGame() {
  console.log(this.game);
}
```

My template:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="game.opponent" class="inputfield"> 
</ion-input>
<ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="game.scoreSvl" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="game.scoreOpponent" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <button ion-button block color="alert" large 
     (click)="saveGame()">Speichern</button>
</ion-item>
```

When i now only change the opponent name (e.g. TSV Marktbergel2) and no change on the score inputs -> the model changes the null values to 0.

Model after change name:

```
opponent: "TSV Marktbergel2"
scoreOpponent: 0
scoreSvl: 0
```

How could i get it, that null values not to be converted into 0?

Comment: works fine here... https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7kppwu?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Still works fine after your edit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yarhqu?file=pages/home/home.ts Please replicate the issue in the stackblitz.

Comment: thx for the hint

Comment: Please in future add **ALL** relevant code in question. As we can see, the code you have presented works fine. And the comment you just posted (and apparently deleted) contains the issue. In future you can try and make a StackBlitz that shows the issue, that way you know for sure that all is included.

Answer (score 0):

my fault. to get the input value (= string) as number, i've implemented in the save method a converter:

```
if(this.game.scoreSvl != null || this.game.scoreSvl != 0) {
            this.game.scoreSvl = this.game.scoreSvl * 1;
            this.game.scoreOpponent = this.game.scoreOpponent * 1;
        }
```

this changed the null values to 0.
i've changed it to:

```
if(this.game.scoreSvl !== null) {
            this.game.scoreSvl = this.game.scoreSvl * 1;
            this.game.scoreOpponent = this.game.scoreOpponent * 1;
        }
```

and it worked!, thx

Comment: you are missing `!==`